# Creating a custom post type using a object oriented approach?

Tags: custom-post-types, oop

I am looking for a good approach regarding the creation of custom post types in WordPress, using object orientation. How can I create CPTs in an clean, organized way?

Take into consideration these 3 scenarios:

1. Plugin for distribution (5.2 compatible)
2. Theme for distribution
3. Own project, with total control over the PHP version and dependencies

Answer (score 8):

I'll answer **scenario #3**, even though it can be adapted for scenarios #1 and #2, too.

WordPress codex [recommends](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#A_word_about_custom_post_types_as_a_plugin) that we create Custom Post Types (CPTs) in a plugin. Following that recommendation, I will write my answer using modern PHP, which is not meant for a distributed plugin, but rather for own projects where you have control over the PHP version running.

In the example code bellow, I will use raw examples just to give an idea of the architecture behind the creation of CPTs in a OOP manner, but in a real project, "my-plugin" would be something like "my-project", and the creation of CPTs would be a sort of module of that plugin.

**my-plugin/my-plugin.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin name: My Custom Post Types
*/
namespace MyPlugin;

use MyPlugin/CPT/Car;

// ... Composer autoload or similar here

Car::register();
```

**my-plugin/CPT/Car.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyPlugin\CPT;

/**
 * Class Car
 *
 * Handles the creation of a "Car" custom post type
*/
class Car
{
    public static function register()
    {
        $instance = new self;

        add_action('init', [$instance, 'registerPostType']);
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', [$instance, 'registerMetaboxes']);

        // Do something else related to "Car" post type
    }

    public function registerPostType()
    {
        register_post_type( 'car', [
            'label' => 'Cars',
        ]);
    }

    public function registerMetaBoxes()
    {
        // Color metabox
        add_meta_box(
            'car-color-metabox',
            __('Color', 'my-plugin'),
            [$this, 'colorMetabox'],
            'car'
        );
    }

    public function colorMetabox()
    {
        echo 'Foo';
    }
}
```

This way we have a namespace for our CPTs, and an object where we can manage it's properties, such as registering the post type, adding or removing metaboxes, etc.

If we are accepting insertion of "Cars" from the frontend, we would use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to receive the POST request and handle it in a [REST Controller Class](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/controller-classes/), but that is out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: Namespaces aren't compatible with PHP 5.2.

Comment: Hi Jacob, read the first sentence of the answer again, please.

Comment: Looks great, but in order to bind your `registerPostType` method into the `init` hook, you are first creating an empty instance of your class. Couldn't you just declare `registerPostType()` and `registerMetaBoxes()` as static? Then you could do `add_action('init', __CLASS__ . '::registerPostType' );` I think that only getters/setters and other helpers for your post type instance should be declared as non-static methods.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use something like this:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Plugin URI: https://my.plugin.com
Description: My plugin description
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Me
Author URI: https://my.website.com
License: GPL2 (or whatever)

Notes:
*/

class myClass {

    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_post_type' ) );

    }

    function create_post_type() {

        $name = 'Foos';
        $singular_name = 'Foo';
        register_post_type( 
            'rg_' . strtolower( $name ),
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name'               => _x( $name, 'post type general name' ),
                    'singular_name'      => _x( $singular_name, 'post type singular name'),
                    'menu_name'          => _x( $name, 'admin menu' ),
                    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( $singular_name, 'add new on admin bar' ),
                    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', strtolower( $name ) ),
                    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New ' . $singular_name ),
                    'new_item'           => __( 'New ' . $singular_name ),
                    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit ' . $singular_name ),
                    'view_item'          => __( 'View ' . $singular_name ),
                    'all_items'          => __( 'All ' . $name ),
                    'search_items'       => __( 'Search ' . $name ),
                    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent :' . $name ),
                    'not_found'          => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $name ) . ' found.'),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $name ) . ' found in Trash.' )
                ),
                'public'             => true,
                'has_archive'        => strtolower($taxonomy_name),
                'hierarchical'       => false,
                'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => $name ),
                'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-carrot'
            )
        );

    }

}

$my_class = new myClass();

?>
```

You can call the `add_action` function to another function too, as long as the action is part of the init callbacks.

Note how the `add_action` function uses an array instead of a string when it is placed inside a class.

You can just use this as the main file in your plugin if you want.

The codex doesn't show using the variables `$name` and `$singular_name`, but i like to start this way so that I can easily change it whenever I want during development.

Here is more information about creating post types:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type